# How do I configure a filter in my web-app

Tags: wildfly, undertow

I have a server which is serving an index.html and bundle.js file (Server:JBoss-EAP/7, X-Powered-By:Undertow/1). I wish to turn off caching for the bundle.js file for my dev environment so that I can update it without having to clear the cache.

I understand that I do this by adding a filter to my web.xml file but I don't know what tilter-class I should be using. How can I learn more?

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need to configure filter in this case. There is the buffer cache is used to cache static resources in JBoss EAP undertow subsystem. The default size of a buffer cache is 10MB.

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:undertow:3.1">
  <buffer-cache name="default"/>
  ....
</subsystem>
```

I think you can use this and change cache buffer size to zero like below or  remove buffer-cache even though I didn't verify yet.

```
/subsystem=undertow/buffer-cache=default/:write-attribute(name=buffer-size,value=0)
:reload
```

You can refer details in the following docs:

1. https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_enterprise_application_platform/7.0/html/configuration_guide/configuring_the_web_server_undertow#undertow-configure-buffer-caches
2. https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_enterprise_application_platform/7.0/html/configuration_guide/reference_material#undertow-attribute-refs

Note that you can also refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37705378/how-to-disable-cache-on-wildfly) on clearing the browser cache.